# How do I remove the #hash entirely from a url in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a url in angular

/something#bla

and I want to get that hash and remove it.

```
var hash = $location.hash();

$location.hash('');
```

makes the url /something#

How can I get rid of the # entirely.

---

Update: no I am not using # to control navigation. It is just used on an individual page to signal whether or not to show a popover. After it shows the popover, I want the # removed by the controller. Sitewide I am already using the html5Mode to do normal urls without the # mark.

Comment: Try `$location.replace($location.path())`.

Comment: @ceejayoz doesn't affect it any.

Comment: @Boaz not a duplicate. I am asking something different

Comment: @RobKohr My bad, sorry. I understand your question now. In that case, why not just do `$window.location.hash = '';`?

Comment: @RobKohr I know I'm 3 years late but did you end up solving that problem? I'm having the exact same use case, any alternate solution is welcomed as well

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Make sure your `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is set then go to your `index` page and set your `<base href="/">` like so. Now you will no longer need the # in your URL.

Comment: Following the OP's clarification, this answer is not relevant anymore I'm afraid.